# Install sir trevor

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

How to install sir trevor? I need a full tutorial, I am beginner and I haven't worked with node.js (I use node 8.12 and when I try to type `npm install`, `npm run dev` or another command, I receive error "deprecated" or 404).
I need explanation"like stupid"

https://pastebin.com/ttGLh5BP

```
$ npm install

> node-sass@3.13.1 install C:\xampp\htdocs\sir\node_modules\sir-trevor\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to install a package with `npm`, you need to add the package name if you don't have it in a `package.json` file. Otherwise simply running `npm install` will only try to download the packages specified in your `package.json` file. If you want to install [sir trevor](http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/docs.html), you need to put the package name after `npm install` like this:

```
npm install sir-trevor
```

To see more details about `npm` read the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)